# How to invoke click a div in web browser using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Here is my code snippet VB.Net code:

```
Try
  Dim elements = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
  For Each element As HtmlElement In elements
    If element.GetAttribute("className") = "next button" Then                    
      element.Focus()                    
      element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
  Next
Catch ex As Exception
  MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

-any help regarding this one?

Comment: Do you have a problem?

Comment: yes, that code wont work but whenever i put the innerText of the div it prompts right

Comment: What does "wont work" mean? Does it explode>

Comment: what i mean is i can get the text between the tag i specified but i cant invoke a click event.

Comment: you are trying to call the clientside javascript click function of the div section from the server side?

Comment: Here is the HTML element i want to invoke a click event:

<div class="next button" style="float: left;" title="Hold down to scroll through records faster.">»</div>

Comment: @Mike_OBrien: seems like that

Comment: This gets messy rather quickly. In this instance you are much better off doing it all through javascript on the client side in my opinion.

Comment: Suggest editing your original question based the comments you've received. It will help future readers of your question better understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this all on the client side instead:

HTML:

```
<div class="next button" style="float: left;" onclick="scroll()" title="Hold down to scroll through records faster.">»</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function scroll() {
    //this is your div click event.
}
```

using JQuery instead of vanilla Javascript:

```
<div id="divBtn" class="next button" style="float: left;" title="Hold down to scroll through records faster.">»</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#divBtn').click(function () {
    //this is your div click event.
});
```

Call Div click event from server side:

For this example I'm useing the asp.net's built in scriptmanager class but I know the AJAX control toolkit has their own version of it so you can really use whichever one you are comfortable with but the function call and parameters may be different.

Once you have the script manager you will need to know the name of your click handler. I'm assuming you are using a javascript function for your click handler since your div does not have a `runat="server"` attribute on it.

So once you get your div's click function assigned and your script manager is all set up you will use the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` function. Documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx).

something like:

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.Page.GetType, "nameOfScript", "DivClickHandler", True)
```

will tell your page to call the div click handler when the page loads.

The problem you are seeing with invokemember is that you are calling it on the server side when the click handler is either on the client side(in javascript) or not registered with the server(since your div does not have the `runat="server"` attribute set. So when you get to the invokemember call in your vb it isn't doing anything because the handler does not exist as far as your server is concerned.

Comment: im using vb.net sir, im trying to click a div using InvokeMember method of vb.net!

Comment: My point is going to the server to do that is very inefficient. If you want to do that on the server then the user will need to click the div on the client side which will send the request over the wire to your server. Your server will perform a complete page load and then build the response, then send the response back to the client side. If you can avoid a full trip to your server then you should go out of your way to do so, you will create a much more streamlined user experience. Having said that, if you insist on making the complete trip I will make some edits and show a way to do that.